# Arduino 2:1 errors DHT + Functions

Tags: arduino

i've been working on a code for a smart bee hive and want to only measure temperature, this isn't my code but I am modifying it to suit the sensors I need.
Unfortunately I am having a few error messages (I am new to arduino and learning a bit too)..so sorry if its obvious.

**Edit: Solved(added brackets to DHT dht()**
tried to figure it out from forums and I see some threads for DHT suggest swapping the dht DHT; for DHT dht but this just creates another error message.

See below for my error messages

ArduinoRaspberryPiHive.ino:9:1: error: ‘dht’ does not name a type
ArduinoRaspberryPiHive.ino: In function ‘void display()’:
ArduinoRaspberryPiHive.ino:44:16: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
ArduinoRaspberryPiHive.ino: In function ‘void loop()’:
ArduinoRaspberryPiHive.ino:64:15: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
ArduinoRaspberryPiHive.ino:69:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
ArduinoRaspberryPiHive.ino:71:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token

```
#include <LCD.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <DHT.h>    


#define DHT21_PIN 10

dht DHT; 

int buttonState1 = 0;
const int But2 = 11; 
 
int buttonState = 0; 
const int But1 = 12; 

byte termometru[8] = {B00100, B01010, B01010, B01110, B01110, B11111, B11111, B01110}; //chart for temperatura

byte picatura[8] = {B00100, B00100, B01010, B01010, B10001, B10001, B10001, B01110,}; //char for humidity

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE); //lcd address
 
void setup()
{
                        // this value is obtained by calibrating the scale with known weights;
                        // reset the scale to 0
    lcd.begin(20,2);
    lcd.backlight();
    lcd.clear(); 
    lcd.createChar(1,termometru);
    lcd.createChar(2,picatura);
    pinMode(But1, INPUT);
    pinMode(But2, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(19200); 
 }

void display()
{

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.write(1); 
  lcd.setCursor(2,1); 
  lcd.print(DHT.temperature, 1); 
  lcd.setCursor(6, 1);
  lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
  lcd.print((char)223); 
  lcd.print("C"); 
   
  lcd.setCursor(10, 1);
  lcd.write(2); 
  lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
  lcd.print(DHT.humidity, 1); 
  lcd.setCursor(14, 1);
  lcd.print(" "); 
  lcd.setCursor(15,1);
  lcd.print("%"); 
 } 
 
void buton()
{
buttonState = digitalRead(But1);
     delay(10); 
    if (buttonState == HIGH) 
        { lcd.backlight(); }
        else {
        lcd.noBacklight(); 
        }}


void loop() 
{
    int chk = DHT.read21(DHT21_PIN);
    display(); 
    buton();
    
    Serial.print("T: ");
    Serial.println(DHT.temperature));
    Serial.print("H: ");
    Serial.println(DHT.humidity);
    Serial.print("W: ");
  
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for a given sensor, you may need to change the parameters based on your hardware. Also note the specific library for your Arduino (or other) microcontroller, not all libraries support all boards:

```
#include <DHT.h>
#define DHTPIN 17       // what pin we're connected to
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
```